# DOM features for Toggle Menu does not work

Tags: javascript

Hi i am trying to create a responsive toggle menu, i have my markup, css and JavaScript code. I think the problem might be with some of the DOM features. If you see the first JavaScript block it is about whether these features are available or not.  When i am resizing the menu nothing change. I tested the code in Google chrome and Firefox. I opened many web pages that have toggle menus on these two browsers and they all work.

```
    //HAML
    !!!
    %html
      %body
       .page
       .header
        .nav#nav
          %nav
          %h1
            %a.skip{:href => "#menu"} Explore this site:
          %ul#menu
            %li.menu-item
              %a{:href => "#typography"} Typography
            %li.menu-item
              %a{:href => "#color"} Color
            %li.menu-item
              %a{:href => "#example"} Examples
            %li.menu-item
              %a{:href => "#more"} More

//CSS
.enhanced .nav .skip{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 1.6em;
  background: #363636;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
}
.enhanced .nav ul {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
}
.enhanced .nav ul.open {
  max-height: 20em;
}
@media screen and (min-width:39em) {
  .page .nav ul {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: inherit;
  }
}

//Javascript    
if ( !("querySelector" in document && "addEventListener" in window &&   "getComputedStyle" in window) ) {
  return;
}
windows.document.documentElement.className += "enhanced";
var nav = document.querySelector( ".nav ul" ), navToggle = document.querySelector( ".nav .skip" );
if ( navToggle ) {
  navToggle.addEventListener( "click", function( e ) {
    if (nav.className == "open") {
      nav.className = "";
    }
    else {
      nav.className = "open";
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  }, false );
}                                              7,24          To
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through in a debugger or adding console logging to figure out exactly which bit isn't doing what you expect? Is your JS being run at a suitable time to ensure that the DOM nodes exist at the point it's trying to use them?

Comment: Thanks for that,
I checked the log as you recommended and i found this error:

Uncaught syntaxError: Illegal return statement

Comment: Is it the `return` shown in your code you posted that is causing this error? The console should give a line number to check. Is the code you posted in a function somewhere, it can't return if it isn't in a function. If you aren't familiar with breakpoints and the `debugger` keyword I suggest looking them up, they'll allow you to step through your code line by line when it runs to see exactly what happens. Adding `console.log` lines to your code is also a great way to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I have to place the return inside a function as the browser debugger indicated. However, the problem i think is that my javascript code is not able to create the "enhanced" class. windows.document.documentElement.className += "enhanced";

I also checked the documentElement to see if it is work in my browser and it just work fine. but i do not really know what is the actual problem

Comment: Do you get an error message? I'd have thought trying to access `windows.document` would throw a `ReferenceError` because `windows` is undefined (it should be `window`). Stepping through in the debugger should allow you to figure out exactly what is happening. When running in the debugger you can stop on that line, check all the values are as expected, step to the next line and then check in the `Elements` section of the dev tools that the relevant change has occurred.

Comment: I already fix that. The code run without any error but the menu still does not work.I am thinking about this:
-I am ordering Javascript to create a new class ".enhanced"
-I am styling my menu like that:
.enhanced .nav ul { css code }
at this point the css code never execute but when i do it like this:
.nav ul { css code }
the css work fine
It can mean:
either the javascript never create ".enhanced" class or the css file cannot read or find the ".enhanced" class
there is no direct link between the css and javascript. the css and javascript talk to each other through the html file.

Comment: It should be easy enough to verify where the problem lies. In your browser's dev tools you can inspect the DOM elements of your page. Check whether the class `enhanced` has been added to the element. If it hasn't then the problem is in your JS, otherwise it lies elsewhere. If it is a JS problem then just set a breakpoint at the top of the relevant code and step through line by line making careful observations about what it is doing, checking that all values are as they should be. One thought that does occur is that you might need a space before the `enhanced` if `className` isn't empty.

Comment: Thanks for your help